# Can we add Books/Wiki links in tag-wiki?

Tags: discussion, support

I see that we have many tags in Hinduism SE and a little one-liner description is given for each tags. I want to ask if it is ok to additionally put some reliable links related to the tags within tag-wiki. eg, in tag 'Vishnu', we can put the link for reliable copy of Vishnu Purana or the wikipedia page for Lord Vishnu. This will help people get some reliable sources of information instead of finding some unreliable or no source on their own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tag editing has two parts:

1. Usage guidance (excerpt)
2. Wiki.

**Yes**, You can add useful links about getting more information on tag in the body of tag-wiki (2<sup>nd</sup> part):

[image]

It can be useful for visitors to get more information and learn topics related to tag.

Besides, also visit [Examples of great tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120586/260388) to learn more.